# compare with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an array called `billItems` in my jquery, and am having values in that like,

```
[TUTION FEE ,SPORTS FEE ,CONVOCATION FEE ]
```

am iterating the `billItems` before adding new item, to avoid duplicate, like

```
for (var i = 0; i < billItems.length; i++) {
    var name = billItems[i];

    if (name == feesItem.ItemName) {  //here ItemName=TUTION FEE
        var validItem = 'False'
    }
}
```

as I mentioned above, am passing the `ItemName` as `TUTION FEE`, but its not comparing the strings and the control not comes into the block even its same. whats wrong with this query, can anyone help me here....

am just appending the datas into a html table like

```
var feesItem = new Object();

  feesItem.ItemName     = $("#txtItemName").val();
  feesItem.Amount       = $("#txtAmount").val();

$("#BillTable > tbody").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
  for (var i = 0; i < feesItemList.length; i++) {  
tab = "<tr><td>" + " <span class='bid'>" + feesItem[i].ItemName + " </span>
       </td><td>" + feesItem[i].Amount + "</td></tr>";

          $("#BillTable > tbody").append(tab);
}
```

its still not comparing the values...

I just tried comparing the values within the for loop like,

```
 var billItems = [];
  $(".bid").each(function () {
      billItems.push($(this).text());
  });

 var validItem = ($.inArray(feesItem[i].ItemName, billItems) < 0);
```

Comment: Can you post your full code block. Creating a `var validItem = false` will just get overwritten on the next iteration, unless you have some other code you've removed from your example?

Comment: can u kindly check my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go on a limb here and guess that your strings are not exactly what they seem. Try changing the comparison to:

```
if ($.trim(name) == $.trim(feesItem.ItemName)) {
```

This will remove any trailing or leading spaces from both arguments before comparison. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/):

```
var billItems = ['TUITION FEE', 'SPORTS FEE', 'CONVOCATION FEE'];
var validItem = ($.inArray(ItemName, billItems) < 0);
```

Comment: still its not working, can u kindly check my updated question

Comment: @Shanish you've got too much going on in the question now to see what's going on.  I can see that you're treating `feesItem` both as a single item, and as an array, though?

Comment: am getting the values in my `billItems` same as I mentioned in my question, If I give some manual values to an array and check as u suggested, its working. But for my case `billItems` its not comparing, I dunno y

Comment: @Shanish you have `feesItem` on its own, `feesItem[i]`, and also `feesItemList`.  I expect once you sort out which of those variables is supposed to be which you'll have solved your problem.

Comment: sorry its feesItem only not feesItemList

Comment: @Shanish so fix those errors, which were not in any way related to your original question, and it should all work out...

Comment: sorry Alnitak, thats my mistake only, after using `trim` its working perfectly, thanks for ur kind response

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's inArray function for this:

Here's the documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

and here's some code to show you how to use it:

```
var myArray = ['TUTION FEE' ,'SPORTS FEE' ,'CONVOCATION FEE' ];
var itemName = 'SPORTS FEE';
var nonExistentItemName = 'OTHER FEE';
var isValid = false;

if($.inArray(itemName, myArray) == -1){
    isValid = true;
}

alert(isValid);

isValid = false;

if($.inArray(nonExistentItemName, myArray) == -1){
    isValid = true;
}

alert(isValid);
```

and here is the jsFiddle to demonstrate it:
http://jsfiddle.net/sPeem/

Comment: thanks Particia, for ur response, am still facing the problem, can u go thru my question once again

Answer (score 1):

Take note of @Rory McCrossan comment about var validItem = false

Also ensure you are comparing string vs string or int vs int javascript can give some false-y vales when cross comparing value types.

As an aside the way to rewrite your code is

```
//Search for a specified value within an array and return its index (or -1 if not found).
var index = jQuery.inArray(ItemName, billItems);

var validItem = index > -1;
```

Comment: thanks heads, for ur response, can u check my question once again , coz am still facing the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
validItem = true;

for(var i = 0; i < billItems.length; i++) {
    var name = billItems[i];

    if(name == ItemName) { 
       validItem = false;
       break;
    }
}

if(validItem){
  billItems.push(ItemName);
}
```

Comment: the comparision is not working, kindly check my updated question